# Google Storage as Hosting static site. DDOS Protection

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cdn, ddos

Google mention that static site can be hosted using 
 https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website also google charges for Egres.

Now if someone do a DOS attach on the site, google will not identify it and just keep on billing . Is there a service that google provide to protect from DDos attack on static site hosting on google storage